# Access value from datalist inside table

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to get the value of Datalist from within a table cell. I have a function that loops through each cell of the table to get the value:

```
function getTableContents() {
    //gets table
    var oTable = document.getElementById('projectsTable');
    var projectNames = [];
    //gets rows of table
    var rowLength = oTable.rows.length;

    //loops through rows    
    for (i = 1; i < rowLength; i++){
        //gets cells of current row  
        var oCells = oTable.rows.item(i).cells;

        //gets amount of cells of current row
        var cellLength = oCells.length;
        //Push the html content of each cell into an array
        projectNames.push(oCells.item(0).innerHTML);
    }
    //Loop through each stored cell and check whether that project exists in the database
    for( i = 0; i < projectNames.length; i++){
        checkUser(projectNames[i]);
    }
}
```

The line that gets the value of the cell returns the html of the datalist but not the actual value. I can get the value a different way using :

```
document.getElementById("listOfProjects").value;
```

However this is undesirable as the table could possibly contain more than one datalist field using the same datalist id. I need some way to be able to get the value of the datalist in a single cell for each cell containing a datalist. Any help is appreciated cheers.

Edit:

Where i first define the datalist:

```
$('.AddNew').click(function(){
    "use strict";
    $('#projectsTable tbody').append("<tr class='child'> \
    <td><input type='text' id='listOfProjects' list='projectNames' placeholder='e.g. Project Name'> \
        <datalist id='projectNames'> \
        </datalist></td> \
    <td> <input type='button' class='RemoveRow' value='Remove Item'> </td></tr>");
```

Where i update the datalist with content:

```
function getProjectNames(){
    //Ensure function is only ran once. Otherwise it causes duplicates in the datalist
    if(!projectNamesRetrieved){
        var dataList = document.getElementById('projectNames');
        if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
            // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
            xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        } else {
            // code for IE6, IE5
            xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
                yourval = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
                document.getElementById("projectsresults").innerHTML = yourval;
                for(var i = 0; i < yourval.length; i++) {
                    var carsOption = "<option value=\"" + yourval[i].Name + "\">" + yourval[i].Name + "</option>";
                    $('#projectNames').append(carsOption);
                }
            }
        };
        xmlhttp.open("GET","getProjectNames.php",true);
        xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
        xmlhttp.send(null);

        projectNamesRetrieved = true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It would help if you can post sample table data. Because, normally .innerHTML should work to extract the value of the cell. But, if its not working then you may try using

```js
projectNames.push(oCells.item(0).innerText);
```

Even if this doesn't help, then please post the test data, so that we can see what you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, ive added the 2 other functions related to the datalist, one where i initially define the datalist and the one where i fill it with options